# how to replace the first element in a CSV with a sequential number?

Tags: csv, cut

I have a csv file like this:

```
5/05/2017;03;07;30;35;43;01;03
9/05/2017;08;12;16;22;26;06;07
12/05/2017;02;20;28;29;44;03;09
16/05/2017;08;11;15;20;30;03;08
19/05/2017;09;11;12;19;30;04;09
23/05/2017;08;15;25;27;42;01;04
26/05/2017;05;07;26;36;39;02;10
...
```

that is, a date, plus a series of numbers followed by `;`.

I need to remove that date in the first position with a number in sequence starting with 1004... like this:

```
1004;03;07;30;35;43;01;03
1005;08;12;16;22;26;06;07
1006;02;20;28;29;44;03;09
1007;08;11;15;20;30;03;08
1008;09;11;12;19;30;04;09
1009;08;15;25;27;42;01;04
1010;05;07;26;36;39;02;10
...
```

I can remove the date using this:

```
cut -f 2-8 -d';' 2.txt | xargs -I{}
```

but how do I add a number in sequence replacing the date?

Comment: That's a delimited text file, but it is not CSV

Comment: Pipe to `nl -s: -i1004`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**awk** solution:

```
awk -F';' 'BEGIN{ i=1004 }{ $1=i++ }1' OFS=';' file
```

- `-F';'` - input field separator
- `i=1004` - starting *increment*

The output:

```
1004;03;07;30;35;43;01;03
1005;08;12;16;22;26;06;07
1006;02;20;28;29;44;03;09
1007;08;11;15;20;30;03;08
1008;09;11;12;19;30;04;09
1009;08;15;25;27;42;01;04
1010;05;07;26;36;39;02;10
```

---

Or you may pass the variable `i` from "outside":

```
awk -F';' '{ $1=i++ }1' i=1004 OFS=';' file
```

Comment: Nice. Only thing I'd change is to pass the starting value from the shell instead of hardcoding in the awk body: `awk -F';' '{$1=i++}1' i=1004 OFS=';' file`

Comment: @glennjackman, you got it

Answer (score 6):

- With `awk`:

  ```
  awk -v cnt=1004 '{ sub("^[^;]+", cnt++) } 1' file.csv
  ```
- With shell:

  ```
  cnt=1004
  while read -r line; do
      printf '%d;%s\n' $cnt "${line#*;}"
      let cnt++
  done <file.csv
  ```
- With `jot`, `paste`, and a shell that can handle `<(...)` redirections:

  ```
  paste -d\; <(jot $(wc -l <file.csv) 1004) <(cut -d\; -f2- file.csv)
  ```
- With Vim:

  ```
  :let cnt=1004 | g/^/ s/^[^;]\+/\=cnt/ | let cnt+=1
  ```
- With Perl:

  ```
  perl -F\; -lpe 'BEGIN{ $cnt=1004 } $F[0]=$cnt++; $_=join ";", @F' file.csv
  ```

Comment: note that implicit `-a` when `-F` is used requires perl v5.20+ ... can also use `perl -F';' -ape 'BEGIN{ $cnt=1004 } s/[^;]+/$cnt++/e' ip.txt`

Comment: If someone is interested, why and how `vim` method works, look here: [How g makes loop in Vim ex command script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28427614/2913477).

Comment: @Sundeep I'm pretty sure the implicit `-a` works since at least 5.12 (but I think it wasn't documented until recently).  Also, you don't need `-F`, this works too: `perl -lpe 'BEGIN{ $cnt=1004 } s/[^;]+/$cnt++/e' file.csv`.  But that's identical to the `awk` approach.

Comment: oh didn't know that, I just checked perldoc... and yeah the -F wasn't needed

Answer (score 2):

Use Python, it's easy to read, understand, and maintain - and it's available on most Unix installations:

```
python - << "EOF" > outfilename
for index, line in enumerate(open("filename"), start=1004):
    linedata = line.strip().split(';')
    linedata[0] = str(index)
    print(';'.join(linedata))
EOF
```